# Is there a technical reason why gnuwin32 doesn't contain ssh?

Tags: windows, command-line, ssh, gnuwin32

How come gnuwin32 while it has a big collection of utilities, seems to have missed out such an important one - SSH?

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html

--
Note- I see Diago closed the question..

The question -can- be answered objectively. Maybe people using GNU tend to use something else as an alternative.

Somebody did comment that SSH isn't GNU. So that would be an objective answer if it were the case.

Though it wouldn't explain openssh.. Why that is.

So these things can be dealt with objectively.

Comment: Simply because ssh is not gnu.

Comment: isn't openssh gnu?

Comment: and if SSH is BSD. Then what were people using instead if they weren't on BSD?

Comment: @barlop. Firstly, please comment on your question rather then editing it. Secondly, then please phrase the question properly. The way it is currently phrased, only the authors of GNU can provide you with a correct answer.

Comment: Figured out a theory. There would be a question of what shell to use. Gnuwin32 stuff runs from cmd.exe not a bash shell like cygwin. But under a cmd shell it's not enough like gnu or any linux ssh.  it wouldn't be just a port it'd be more windowy. The idea of doing ssh and running DIR maybe seems to the developers to be more of a windowy thing to do and so not a port. Just a thoery

Comment: people aren't really "on GNU".  Practically speaking, outside of the mind of its creator(who thinks GNU is an operating system), GNU is  a bunch of utilities/programs..The first bunch were written by GNU, and the rest just have a GNU license. People don't use GNU exclusively.   OpenSSH is under BSD license.   Whatever license the original SSH was under, it was not BSD and not GNU.   And gnuwin32, despite its name, is not an official thing.. and it's not really kept up to date. And it's just some programs, not necessarily GNU.

Answer (score 0):

Because we've already been blessed with [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) :)

Comment: isn't putty just a client?

Comment: @ the person negging, it was a joke. SSH is not a GNU utility.

Comment: Putty is a client, so there isn't much connection between your strange joke and my question. You could've named something nothing to do with  ssh to be clearer.  By the way, I think gnuwin32 does contain non GNU stuff as well.